# CRM 2015 Customer Portal fails to import

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I recently installed CRM 2015 in order to develop a portal solution. According to the documentation I will have to first import the base portal to be able to do any work. According to the documentation, the portal will be found on the SDK directory and this was never the same. I downloaded the portal from pinpoint and tried uploading the MicrosoftXrmCustomerPortal_managed.zip. During importation it rolls back with the error

```html
23:47:14.56 SDK Message Processing Step {e38be3eb-0b93-e111-b0d0-00155d03a708} CustomerPortal.Plugins.EventRegistration: Create of campaignresponse CustomerPortal.Plugins.EventRegistration: Create of campaignresponse   Failure 0x80040217 plugintype With Id = 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 Does Not Exist
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the dlls included in the solution have different Public keys than the entries in the solution.xml and customizations.xml files so while you wait for MS to release a corrected solution do the following.

1. Extract the contents of MicrosoftXrmCustomerPortal_managed.zip to disk.
2. Open the file solution.xml in your favourite editor.
3. Carry out a find and replace of PublicKeyToken=6d5f14a277660d59 with PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
4. Then carry out a find and replace of PublicKeyToken=ace90226af8624d4 with PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
5. Save the file and close it
6. Open the file customizations.xml then repeat steps 3 - 5.
7. Select all the files and folders in the extracted directory and re zip them.
8. Import the new zip file into dynamics crm.

Cheers

Richard